# Error while installation iOS app on device

Tags: ios, xcode, mobileprovision

I met a strange problem for iOS app, created in VS with Xamarin. When I created mobile provision in Apple developer account for testing app on real devices (AdHoc type, like Xamarin tutorial shows), I tried to install app to devices, added to provision. Installation was successful. After that I tried to install app to devices not added to provision. Installation was fault. But when I deleted all devices except 1 from provision and updated provision on my Mac nothing changed. I still can install app to devices, was in provision before. 
Can anybody help with this problem?

Comment: Did you make new build after updating provision file , and tried to install that on old devices ? or you are still trying to install the old build ?

Comment: @MandeepKumar After I created new provision (only 1 device) I deleted all previous provisions, installed on Mac host-machine. Then I install new provision on Mac-host,and after that in Visual Studio I choose for build new provision in provisions list and created app (*.ipa file). And this *.ipa I successfully install to the old devices.

Comment: After delete all devices, did you update the AdHoc profiles again?

Comment: @lowleetak As a told in my previous comment - yes.

Comment: @Adeptus I mean in Apple developer portal, did you edit the AdHoc profiles?

Comment: @lowleetak Provision = Provisioning profile. Or there are any other way to get new *,mobileprovision file, not only through creating new profile?

Comment: @Adeptus In Apple developer portal, after you remove the devices, go to "Provisioning Profiles" and click on your AdHoc profile. Click on the Edit button and edit the devices for that profiles and redownload it in your machine.

Comment: @lowleetak As I told in my first comment - I created new profile with only 1 device in devices list, downloaded and installed it. So you just suggest what I already did.